# Encrypt Java MIDP Application

Tags: java, security, encryption, java-me, midp

How to encrypt java MIDP application?
I need to encrypt the application, not obfuscate, I already use ProGuard to obfuscate my application, but the classes files still can be decompiled.

I have tried using ClassGuard to encrypt my Mobile Aplication, but ClassGuard does not support MIDP application. It only support java desktop application.

Comment: After obfuscation classes can be de-compiled but they will not be in easily readable form no one can dare to debug the source and modify it

Comment: And if you encrypt them they can still be decrypted by the user. After all, where would you store the decryption key?

Comment: Who will decrypt the application? Why do you want to encrypt the application? What are you protecting?

Answer (score 2):

Encryption, in addition to obfuscation, just makes a program harder to hack.

It 's like having police standing outside your vault door. It doesn 't make it impossible; it just makes it harder.

Consequently, when you obfuscate you still have class files, though the class files might be a.class, and b.class and c.class they are still present in the jar and you can decompile them easily.

With encryption like, for instance, classguard you have a.classx, b.classx, and c.classx in the jar. This means that you have to go through the additional step of dumping the class from the running application. Not something everyone can do, and certainly harder then just unzipping the class from the jar file.

In my opinion, security should be applied in layers; Class encryption is just another layer that makes it harder to hack a java program.